# TestNG groups with custom SpringContext

Tags: kotlin, testng, integration-testing, spring-transactions, testng-dataprovider

I am doing a refactoring of my entire test suite by grouping the different test types into multiple groups ( unittest, integration test ...tests).

TestNG allows you to do that with the groups annotation like below

```
@Test(groups = [ "integrationTest" ])
class MyGroupedTest : MySprpingTestClass() {

  private lateinit var myVar: MyVarService 

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var myRepo: MyRepo

  @Autowired
  @Named("requires_new")
  lateinit var txTemplate: TransactionTemplate
```

I encounter that when adding the group to my Test class, TestNg throughs does not loads my SpringApplicationContext and claims that MyRepo dependency is not initliazed

The following link redirects me to
[image]

But I do not see how does it translate to my problem.

Note that my class is inheriting from a base class which bootstraps a small Spring application with few beans and a connection to database with not issues
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add some additional details with respect to the base class, so that we can try to execute it or help share a standalone project that can be used to reproduce the issue. With whatever details you have shared, its a bit difficult.

Comment: Sure1 let me try to edit .